Assigned variable in memory location 0x40 is returned in 0x80
I'm trying to understand how assembly works with memory and the free memory pointer.
Given the following:
        function test() public pure returns(uint){

            assembly {
                mstore(mload(0x40), 5)
                return(0x40, 32) //result: 128
            }
        }

        function test2() public pure returns(uint){

            assembly {
                mstore(mload(0x40), 5)
                return(0x80, 32) //result: 5
            }
        }

Why is test() returning 128, I can't think of anything with that number. Is that 0x80?
For test2() we're loading the free memory pointer (0x40) and then storing the number 5 there. But when returning 0x80 we get the number 5. Is that because when performing any action it happens in 0x40 and gets directed to 0x80 when we want to return it? If yes, why?
I read that 0x40 points to 0x80 but how does that work. Is that a simple rule that 0x40 == 0x80 or something?
What's even more confusing is that the following returns 0:
        function test() public pure returns(uint){
            assembly {
                mstore(mload(0x80), 5)
                return(0x80, 32) //result: 0
            }
        }

An other example:
        function test() public pure returns(uint){
            uint num = 111;
            assembly {
                return(0x40, 32) //result: 128
            }
        }

        function test3() public pure returns(uint){
            uint num = 111;
            assembly {
                return(0x80, 32) //result: 0
            }
        }
}

When declaring a variable in memory, I would assume that it would be either in 0x40 or 0x80. But why isn't it showing up?

I would highly suggest reading through the Layout in Memory page in the Solidity docs.
Here is an excerpt that shows the reserved space in memory:
0x00-0x3f (64 bytes): scratch space for hashing methods
0x40-0x5f (32 bytes): currently allocated memory size (aka. free memory pointer)
0x60-0x7f (32 bytes): zero slot
One important note is that, since these slots are reserved, the free memory pointer is initialized to point to the next free slot (which is 0x80). The rest of memory is zeroe'd out. I'll explain your examples with this info as a reference
Example 1:
function test() public pure returns(uint){
    assembly {
        mstore(mload(0x40), 5)
        return(0x40, 32) //result: 128
    }
}

You are doing a mload(0x40), which gets the free memory pointer (which as explained above starts at 0x80.) Then it processes mstore(0x80, 5), storing the value 5 at memory slots 0x80. Then return(0x40, 32) sets the return data as the 32 bytes starting at slot 0x40, which is the free memory counter. The free memory counter was never changed from 0x80, so it returns it here again
Your test2 function is correct because it is reading from slot 0x80, which is the slot you wrote 5 to
Example 2:
function test() public pure returns(uint){
    assembly {
        mstore(mload(0x80), 5)
        return(0x80, 32) //result: 0
    }
}

Stepping through this one, you do a mload(0x80) which resolves to 0 since there is nothing stored at 0x80 yet. Then mstore(0,5), storing 5 at the slot 0x00. Then you return the 32 bytes at 0x80, which is 0 because nothing was ever stored there
Example 3:
    function test() public pure returns(uint){
        uint num = 111;
        assembly {
            return(0x40, 32) //result: 128
        }
    }

The num variable is stored on the stack, not in memory, so it wont affect the free memory pointer. Then you're just returning the free memory pointer, which is still the default 0x80
